# How To Clear Visual Studio Deploy Flag in a Build Configuration with CMake

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

I get an error running a solution generated by CMake for Visual Studio 2017 that had no problem with Visual Studio 2015. The solution also includes 3 VS projects not generated by CMake.  The solution builds and runs but the first time run will generate the following error on each of the 3 projects.

```
error MSB4057: The target "Deploy" does not exist in the project
```

If I select Configuration Manager from the Build menu before the program is run, the Deploy flag is only checked on the 3 projects.
I'm using CMake 3.8.1 and Visual Studio 2017 15.2. If I generate the solution for VS2015 and load it in VS2015, Configuration Manager shows the 3 projects with the Deploy flag clear. Loading the same project into VS2017 will shows the 3 Deploy flags checked and will produce the errors on the first run. Subsequent runs will not produce errors and Configuration Manager will grey out the Deploy box on those projects.

However, If I look at the .sln before loading into Visual Studio 2017, it does not contain a a Deploy entry for these projects. VS2017 creates it when it loads the .sln and will save it out unless the it is built and run, in which case it will delete the entry when it saves out the .sln.

```
{68A5DD20-7057-448B-8FE0-B6AC8D205509}.Release|x64.Deploy.0 = Release|x64
```

How do I get CMake to create the solution without VS2017 creating the Deploy flags even temporarily?